# Need help choosing colors for info graphics

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-theory, information-graphics

i am trying to create a info-graphics design in adobe illustrator, i divided a circle into 18 pieces  i applied gradients colors to each pieces.i tried choosing colors from info graphic images from google search, but i am not able produce good balance between the colors. no matter what i do the colors does not complement each. how do make this circle better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At 18 slices in the chart I would explore alternative ways to display this information, but we don't have enough context to come up with a better option.